# Using class outside of While where it is defined

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, scope, datareader

I am trying to have my application check the Admins table in my SQL database, and then get the name of the department that the current user belongs to. After that, I want to check a different table and choose only the news items that belong to that department.

The below shows how I'm going about it, however the problem lies in using the mydepartment variable outside of the While loop (which is used within the second SQL Query).

Everything works except that. Any help would be appreciated.

```
public string username = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name.Split('\\')[1];
public string mydepartment;

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lblUser.Text = username.ToString();
    SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection();
    myConnection.ConnectionString = @"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFileName=|DataDirectory|\Database1.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True";

    myConnection.Open();
    string selectretrieveSQL = ("SELECT * FROM Admins WHERE userid = '" + username.ToString() + "'");
    SqlCommand retrieveinfocmd = new SqlCommand(selectretrieveSQL, myConnection);
    SqlDataReader reader = retrieveinfocmd.ExecuteReader();

    while (reader.Read())
    {
        ListItem newItem = new ListItem();
        newItem.Text = reader["Department"].ToString();
        newItem.Value = reader["userid"].ToString();
        UserIds.Items.Add(newItem);
        mydepartment = reader["Department"].ToString();
        mydepartmentlbl.Text = reader["Department"].ToString();
    }
    reader.Close();

    string selectNewsSQL = ("SELECT * FROM NewsItems WHERE Department = '" + mydepartment + "'");
}
```

Comment: You don't say how it's not working.

Comment: I cleaned up the code formatting, and it looks like `mydepartment` should work fine if there is actually any data for that username.

Comment: Also, a few comments: Don't do SQL like that. Use parameterized SQL. ESPECIALLY for web based stuff, but as a general, ALWAYS used parameters. Don't concatenate strings. That's just SQL injection waiting to happen. Also, in 3 places you do reader["Department"].ToString(). Do it once, store it in a variable and use that variable. reader[""] will cost more in terms of performance. Finally, for your SQL objects, use the using keyword for them. They're disposable and not getting diposed.

Comment: Also, `mydepartment` is a string variable, not a class.

Comment: Can a user belong to more than one department, I.e. is the database query guaranteed to always return just one row, or is it possible for multiple rows to be returned?

Comment: You're vulnerable to SQL injection in this.

Answer (score 3):

First, I highly recommend you create some classes to hold properties for your database objects.

For example, maybe your **Admin** would look like this:

```
public class Admin
{
  public string Username { get; set; }
  public string Department { get; set; }

  // .. More properties here
}
```

Next, you should make some methods that do the dirty work for you. I'd start with the database initialization:

```
static SqlConnection InitializeDatabase(string connectionString)
{
  var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
  connection.Open();

  return connection;
}
```

So maybe you have a method that gets the proper `Admin` for you:

```
static IEnumerable<Admin> GetAdminsByUsername(SqlConnection connection, 
                                              string username)
{
  var adminList = new List<Admin>();

  // You really should be using stored procedures here instead...
  var query = @"SELECT * FROM Admins WHERE Username = @Username";

  using (var command = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
  {
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", username);

    using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
    {
      while (reader.Read())
      {
        var adminUsername = reader["Username"].ToString();
        var adminDepartment = reader["Department"].ToString();

        var admin = new Admin
        {
          Username = adminUsername,
          Department = adminDepartment
        };

        adminList.Add(admin);
      }
      reader.Close();

      return adminList;
    }
  }
}
```

Then your `Page.Load` might look like this:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  var connectionString = @"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFileName=|DataDirectory|\Database1.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True";

  using(var connection = InitializeDatabase(connectionString))
  {
    var admin = GetAdminsByUsername(connection, username).FirstOrDefault();

    if(admin == null)
    {
      // No admin was found, do something here.
      return;
    }

    var newItem = new ListItem();
    newItem.Text = admin.Department.
    newItem.Value = admin.Username;

    // Keep your controls named consistently, don't use shorthands
    // since you already have IntelliSense to auto-complete them for you

    usernameLabel.Text = admin.Username;
    departmentLabel.Text = admin.Department;
  }
```

That should at least get you started in the right direction.

Answer (score 2):

Leaving aside everything that the previous posters have said, all of which I agree with, the code as presented will not work because during that while loop, what you are doing is populating a list box or dropdown of some kind with user information (Department as the Display and Userid as the value).

If you want to be able to then get some more information based on the Department, you need to handle that listbox or select's SelectedIndexChanged event (or similar), get the currently selected text value and *then* create that second query and execute it.

However; please do follow the advice of the previous posters, you don't have to use stored procedures but you really ought to be using parameters on your queries. Imagine what would happen if some nasty person managed to pass a UserID of **l33t';drop table Admins**. Your page would then execute this:

```
SELECT * FROM Admins WHERE userid = 'l33t';drop table Admins;
```

oops....I know in your specific case you're not accepting user input but sooner or later you will...

Hope this helps.